# Does Oracle otimize SELECT FOR UPDATE that don't have any entries?

Tags: oracle

I have a Stored Procedure something along the lines below. I have some indications that the SELECT only has 15% of the cases where ID exists. I'm seeing that the UPDATEs are only being executed those 15% of the times. Does Oracle somehow optimize this?

```
BEGIN
        SELECT ID
        FROM Sessions
        WHERE ID = idt FOR UPDATE;

        UPDATE Sessions
        SET Expire = SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) + 1/288
        WHERE ID = idt

        COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  The WHERE clauses of the SELECT and UPDATE are identical, so they will affect the same rows.  What are you asking?

Comment: What seems to be happening is the following: Some 2K SELECTs are done per hour, but it seems that only 300 UPDATEs are being done. When I checked how many rows the SELECTs were returning, the number is also 300 per hour...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes there is more going on, but I'm pretty sure doesn't have to do with this issue ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is "No".
Oracle doesn't make any predictions about data that persisted in DB tables.
This is not deterministic thing.
Only thing that Oracle do for you is a soft-parse of your SQL-s.

Pseudocode in your question is a bit confusing.
In real code you must make select for update to some variable and then process that variable.
Maybe part of answer of your question is hiding in your variable processing method.
There is many ways to avoid processing part of code.

If you use **SELECT INTO** simple scalar variable then you got **NO DATA FOUND** exception and no **UPDATE** will follow.
If you use bulk into collection and **IN (SELECT FROM TABLE(my collection))** then you got no exceptions and no **UPDATEs**.

Some advices about performance:

1. Maybe you want to process **many** sessions?
   In that case you may wanted to [use bulk operations](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/bulk-binds-and-record-processing-9i#bulk_collect) like:

```
SELECT id BULK COLLECT INTO col_sessions_id from SESSIONS WHERE ...
FOR UPDATE
```

and then

```
  FORALL i IN col_sessions_id.first .. col_sessions_id.last
  UPDATE SESSIONS SET ... WHERE ID = col_sessions_id(i)
```

2. When you use **FOR UPDATE** without any qualifiers you [may got a hung](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_for_update.htm).
   Without **NOWAIT** or explicit **WAIT** clause it will be waiting until lock will be acquired.
   Do you really want it?
   Maybe you need to use **NOWAIT** or **SKIP LOCKED** clause instead?
   In highload production cases this patterns very common used.
   Of course you must to process exceptions and adjust your business logic.
3. Use direct access to rows after you make your **FOR UPDATE** select.
   Remember that you can select **ROWID** instead of **ID** and use them later to update.
   If you pass **ROWID** to your WHERE clause then Oracle make you DML very fast without even needing to use indexes.
   [See simple **ROWID** example here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rowids-for-plsql-performance).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I do have a SELECT INTO and I also do have a "EXCEPTION  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL; " and I forgot to put it up, trying to hide part of the code :-( And, of course, this explains it all!